# How to search for any file with a specified extension using Gobuster

Tags: enumeration, wildcard

A website allocates random file names to uploads and I am trying to enumerate through the folder that the files are uploaded to using Gobuster.

I know the extension of my file type, but not the file name. Is there a way to invoke the -x flag to look for file extensions without invoking the -w flag? Or some way to invoke the -w flag to search for every file?

Normally you would use:

```
gobuster dir -u [URL]/uploads -w [wordlist] -x [extension]
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
gobuster dir -u [URL]/uploads -x [extension]
```

Is there a way to invoke a wildcard in the -w flag?

```
gobuster dir -u [URL]/uploads -w [wildcard_to_cover_all_files?] -x [extension]
```

Comment: `-w` very clearly is the path to the wordlist file, so there would be no "wildcard" possibility there. Gobuster isn't a "fuzzing" brute force tool that can try random combinations. It uses a pre-defined list. So, this isn't the right tool for what you want. Why do you want to stick to Gobuster?

Comment: @schroeder I use a combination of gobuster, ffuf and dirb for my enumeration. If you have any other recommendations I'm all ears - always happy to learn about new tools. I didn't think it was possible to do this with gobuster but I wanted to check in case I was missing something.